# The Author column in the CVS history disappeared from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, cvs

It happened since yesterday that the Author column in the CVS history disappeared in my Eclipse IDE. I have gone through all the menus in Eclipse and all kinds of Google search but couldn't figured out how to add it back. Does anyone have a clue on it?

I am using the latest Eclipse (Helios) on 64-bit Windows 7. I used the following steps to show CVS history: right click the file name under Project Explorer => Team => Show History.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

This happened in my eclipse as well. Unfortunately the other answers did not help me but I was able to fix it by manually editing the cvs plugins stored preference.

Close Eclipse.

Go to the path `$WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui` in your filesystem. Where `$WORKSPACE` is the directory that has your Eclipse workspace.

Edit the file `dialog_settings.xml` in that directory.

You should see an `item` element with the attribute `key="COL_AUTHOR"` change the `value` attribute to be non-zero (I set mine to 100). Specifically, the Xpath for the attribute your trying to change is `//section[@name="org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.CVSHistoryTableProvider"]/item[@key="COL_AUTHOR"]/@value`

Start up Eclipse and the problem should be fixed.

Comment: I had double-clicked on the separator between the "Tags" and "Revision Time" columns and the width of the "Tags" column exploded! I could not find the edge again to reset it so the only way to set the width back to a sane value was by opening the `dialog_settings.xml` the way you described and set the value back down from 54943! Thanks

Edit: I also found out that it was posted [as a bug](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/154509/)

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me as well.  It turns out that the author column can be completely collapsed in between the 'Revision Time' column and the 'Comment' column.  I had to carefully put my mouse cursor on the right side of the divider between the two columns and drag to the right, in effect resizing the author column to not have 0 width.  The UI then exposes the author column, which should always be there if the Revision and Comment columns are present.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my eclipse environment, so have no way to go back to the old one to confirm that. But thanks for the help, and I will keep it in my mind in future.