# Eclipse History view broken

Tags: eclipse, cvs

by double-clicking in between the headers of the Eclipse History view (Revision, Tags, etc.) each fields gets resized (enlarged to the right) to accommodate the size of the longest value.

Now, because my Tags columns contains very long values (long strings containing the list of tags) when I double-clicked on the headers between Tags and the next header (Revision Time), the Tags column got enlarged to the right so much that the Revision Time column has disappeared.

I can't find a way to get to the Revision Time column. Scrolling to the right using the horizontal scroll line is useless.

Any idea?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

had this happen with eclipse 3.7 on Windows

as per https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=313480

- close Eclipse
- delete .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui/dialog _settings.xml file
- start Eclipse
- do history and see it work

Comment: +1 for mentions about .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui. I had a problem with cvs history view for xml files and I fixed it by clearing all settings from org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same. Thanks to  [Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260633/dev). 
I found the answer [The Author column in the CVS history disappeared from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738661/the-author-column-in-the-cvs-history-disappeared-from-eclipse)

Go to the path `$WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui` in your filesystem. Where `$WORKSPACE` is the directory that has your Eclipse workspace.

Edit the file `dialog_settings.xml` in that directory.

find `<item value="put something reasonable here" key="COL_TAGS"/>`